# Stuck in nested While loop

Tags: python, while-loop, nested-loops

Below is the code for my program. I am trying to get this to ask the user if they want to enter a set of test scores. If yes the program runs, Gets the test scores, when the user types end, the loop ends, adds the scores and then gives the average. Then it is supposed to ask if the user wants to add another set of test scores. If yes, it runs again. If not, it stops and has a closing statement.

I have the second while loop inside the main while loop. When I run the code, it does not even run the main while loop. Below is what it shows when I answer y (yes) to the question.

```
Enter test scores
Enter end to end input
======================
Get entries for another set of scores?  y
Enter your information below
Get entries for another set of scores?
```

It does not run the original while loop; which lets the user input scores, hit "end" when finished, calculates the scores, gives the average, and finally asks the user if they want to enter another set of test scores.

Any suggestions? I have the complete code as I have it in PyCharm below.

```
print("The Test Scores application")
print()
print("Enter test scores")
print("Enter end to end input")
print("======================")

# initialize variables
counter = 0
score_total = 0
test_score = 0
get_entries = 'y'
while test_score != 999:
    while True:
        get_entries = input("Get entries for another set of scores?  ")
        if get_entries == 'y':
            print("Enter your information below")
        else:
            print("Thank you for using the Test Scores application. Goodbye!")
    test_score = input("Enter test score: ")

    if test_score == 'end':
        break
    elif (int(test_score) >= 0) and (int(test_score) <= 100):
        score_total += int(test_score)
        counter += 1
    elif test_score == 999:
        break
    else:
        print("Test score must be from 0 through 100. Score discarded. Try again.")

    # calculate average score
average_score = round(score_total / counter)

# format and display the result
print("======================")
print("Total Score:", score_total,
      "\nAverage Score:", average_score)
```

Comment: The nested loop is the code that I used from a previous set of code. It worked; when I used it in the other code. However, it wasn't part of a nested loop.

Comment: That's fine, have you tried fixing it as outlined in my answer?

Comment: Yes. However, when I left the while True loop inside the original while loop, I got an indentation error. Where in the first while loop should I put my while True loop? I have positioned it right underneath the "e" in 'while' but that still didn't work. I tried positioning it, in between the code of the first while loop and that did not work either. I am at a loss in where or how the while True loop is supposed to be put in the first while loop, to make it all work concisely.

Comment: Having the `w` of the `while True` immediately underneath the `e` of the outer `while` loop should work correctly. If the code you have posted is not exactly the same as the code you are writing in PyCharm, then it is difficult for me to determine what could be wrong. I suggest you trim back your code to almost nothing, then build it up a tiny piece at a time until it either works or breaks again, at which point you should have a better idea about what has broken it.

Comment: I edited my original question and posted the same code as I have it in my PyCharm. I put the while True loop underneath the "e" in the first while loop.  I have the output; when I Run the program, listed as part of the question. Is there any way that you can take my code and run it in your IDE or can you tell by looking where I need to make adjustments?

Comment: This is a new question now, so really should be a new question. But in any case see my updated answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your inner loop is indented too far. `while True:` has 5 spaces before it, while everything else is indented by 4 spaces. Also, while we're talking about indentation, you have a `break` that is incorrectly indented too.

To fix this:

- delete one space from before `while True:`
- add three more spaces before `break`
- for bonus points, also delete one space from before each of the 5 lines inside the nested `while` so that they are indented by 8 or 12 spaces.

---

#### Hint for the updated question:

Look at the implementation of your inner loop. Under what circumstances would the program exit that loop to continue on to `test_score = ...`?

Comment: It would exit using a 'break' after the else statement, in the while True loop. I added a 'break'. Then I run the code. It executed without any errors. However, it did the first part.... The system asks: "Get entries for another set of test scores?". I selected y for yes. It then said enter the information below, as well as, the same "Get entries for another set of test scores?. It did not run my main while loop.  I tried moving the test_score = input("Enter test score: ") above the while True: statement. However, that did not work either. I'm lost on how to make this program work.

Comment: You have your loops back-to-front, and you have code outside of your loops that you want to run inside the loops. I suggest you strip it back until it works as desired for a single set of test scores. Then carefully look at which lines of code need to be run for _each_ set of scores, and turn that into a function (there will be a loop inside your function). Then write another loop that only calls the function and then asks the user if they want to do another set.

Answer (score 0):

The code edited below may be of help and that's what you wanted to do probably.

```
print("The Test Scores application")
print()
print("Enter test scores")
print("Enter end to end input")
print("======================")

# initialize variables
counter = 0
score_total = 0
test_score = 0
get_entries = 'y'
while test_score != 999:
    while True:
        get_entries = input("Get entries for another set of scores?  ")
        if get_entries == 'y':
            print("Enter your information below")
        else:
            print("Thank you for using the Test Scores application. Goodbye!")
            break
        test_score = input("Enter test score: ")

        if test_score == 'end':
            break
        elif (int(test_score) >= 0) and (int(test_score) <= 100):
            score_total += int(test_score)
            counter += 1
        elif test_score == 999:
            break
        else:
            print("Test score must be from 0 through 100. Score discarded. Try again.")
    break

    # calculate average score
average_score = round(score_total / counter)

# format and display the result
print("======================")
print("Total Score:", score_total,
      "\nAverage Score:", average_score)
```